# Rotating Uniformly Charged Ring

Tags: electromagnetism

Does a uniformly charged ring, rotating about its axis produce Electric Field on its axis( as a non-rotating charged ring does)?

I am comfortable with elementary ideas that would come along with any given explanation.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate it yourself? If so, where are you having trouble?

Comment: I think this is discussed, indirectly in one of the  Feynman Red Books

Comment: I think you should share your attempts first. So that we can understand what caused your trouble ?

Comment: I am confused about the idea/concept. It wasn't a question from a book.